# ProcDump dumps wrong thread

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, procdump

Looks ProcDump dumps a post mortem dump of the wrong thread. Made ProcDump the JIT-debugger:

```
C:\>procdump -ma -i c:\mydumps
```

Made a test program C++ MFC:

```
int* ptr = 0;
switch(message) {
...
case IDM_CRASH:
   *ptr = 23;
   break;
...
```

Selecting the Crash item from the menu (of the program ProcDumpTest.exe), the application crashes and a dump is made. The dump however shows (windbg) a stack and an instruction pointer (eip = 7c90e514) of an unexpected thread. How to get the stack trace of thread where the error occurred?

```
00400000 - 004a0000 ProdDumpTest.exe
07c90000 - 07c9b000 ntdll.dll
```

Got the same problem in a more serious case. Thanks for any help! GMore

Comment: First check what the Windbg !analyze command tells you.  It will select the crashing thread if it can see the exception.

Comment: [.ecxr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562945(v=vs.85).aspx) command instructs the debugger to use the context record that is associated with the current exception as the register context. After you run .ecxr, the debugger can access the most important registers and the stack trace for this thread. The [k*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551943(v=vs.85).aspx) commands display the stack frame.

Comment: The ~ command lists one thread (the wrong one). The .ecxr command reports that the Minidump... doesn't have an exception context (HRESULT 0x80004002). I thought the procdump -ma option would create a full dump. Seems I miss the point somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

After the .reload /f command, the !analyze -v showed the correct information. Thanks for the help.